# Can I re-enable secure boot on a computer after I disabled It

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

I turned off secure Boot And Then I Booted Into Windows.

Can I re-enable it safely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can re-enable this feature safely if your operating system is compatible with this security mode.

For Windows, you need at least Windows 8.